# Allowing docker-in-docker on dc/os?

Tags: docker, airflow, dcos, docker-in-docker

I am trying to schedule 'docker run' jobs using Airflow, on DC/OS. This requires the ability to start docker containers from within the docker container which contains Airflow. I am able to do this on OSX but just running:

```
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock {image name}
```

Is there an equivalent way for me to do this using DC/OS?

Answer (score 0):

The DC/OS way would be scheduling jobs via Mesos Master. That means writing a framework that would negotiate resource allocation (= "starting a Docker job") with the Master. Thus starting the job on any node in the cluster with available resources for the task. Such framework is yet another service that is responsible for resource negotiation with the Mesos Master. There are many examples of such frameworks:

- [kafka](http://universe.dcos.io/#/package/kafka/version/latest)
- [elastic](http://universe.dcos.io/#/package/elastic/version/latest)
- [cassandra](http://universe.dcos.io/#/package/cassandra/version/latest)

Most of the are build on top of [dcos-commons](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-commons) service-framework.

A workaround would be starting the job via another existing framework, e.g. Marathon. Marathon offers [a REST API](https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/deploying-services/marathon-api/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Airflow has an own Apache Mesos scheduler implementation, which is pretty nice and exactly what you are looking for. If you are running DC/OS you can install multiple Mesos schedulers which can start tasks on Mesos independently and actually there is no need for a privileged mode.

You can find the Airflow documentation here:
https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html#scaling-out-on-mesos-community-contributed

In this described scenario, the `Airflow Server` would be started via marathon (=DC/OS service section) and this `Airflow Server` would register itself as scheduler to Mesos and then it is able to start regular Mesos tasks.